# Factory function syntax in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't understand the c type marker syntax here :
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/12/factory-functions-typescript.aspx

```
function CreateCustomer<c extends ICustomer>(cust:{new(): c;}, 
                                         name: string, age: number): c
```

Can someone explain what is c above in the 3 different places ?

Answer (score 2):

1st c is declaration that collection variable have to extend ICustomer (in app you can have VIPCustomer, MegaCustomer...)

Then 2nd c is just safetyguard that constructor of c is 100% extending ICustomer (returning this object into cust)

The last c is return type of the whole function.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

1. `<c extends ICustomer>` means "`c` is a type that extends `ICustomer`"
2. `cust:{new(): c;}` means "`cust` is a function that can be called with `new cust()` and will return an object of type `c`"
3. `function CreateCustomer/*...*/(/*...*/): c` means "function `CreateCustomer` returns an object of type `c`"

The function can be called like that:
`var john:Customer = CreateCustomer(Customer, "John", 35)`
Where `Customer` is a class extending `ICustomer` interface.